# how to add static method in TableAdapter

Tags: .net, datatableadapters

i'm working with .net 2 and visual studio 2005

I want to know how to add/create a static method in a TabelAdapter

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://kohari.org/2008/04/04/extension-methods-in-net-20/) a blog post about implementing static "extension methods" in plain old .NET 2.0 (for those who are unable to upgrade a particular project for whatever reason).  It references [Scott Hanselman's post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoExtensionMethodsWorkAndWhyWasANewCLRNotRequired.aspx) on the subject, as well as [another example post](http://www.codethinked.com/post/2008/02/Using-Extension-Methods-in-net-20.aspx).

Comment: The generated adapters are `partial` classes, no need for (pseudo) extension methods.

Comment: But I see no reason for a -1 either.